# "Share" Content from Another Site as Post

Tags: plugins, rss

I'm building a site for a user who's not terribly tech-savvy but who wants to be able to "share" content he finds around the web on his site in addition to writing his own posts. He's really mentally focused on "RSS feeds," though I don't think he really even knows what an RSS feed is.

He does *not* want an automatically updating feed of content from around the web.

Rather, he seems to be really interested in something basically like "Press This." He wants to be able to find a single article that he's interested in sharing, and click a button to share it (or copy/paste as he would on Facebook) and have it show up as a post on his site that links back to the original article.

Press This would honestly be a great solution, except that the theme we're using makes heavy use of featured images (pretty much, you want every article to have one) and it's super inconvenient to insert featured images with Press This. The workflow would involve either downloading an image from the original page, or adding it to the post in Press This, then removing it, then going to the full post editor to set the newly retrieved image as the featured image, then publishing. Hardly a convenient process, and this guy is still wrapping his head around the basics of writing posts.

Are there alternatives out there? Requirements are:

- Roughly one-step process to "share" content from another site
- Allows setting featured image intuitively (or automatically)
- Creates a post
- Easily (or automatically) adds a link to the original article

Things I've tried

- Press This (no featured images)
- Various RSS-related plugins (all seem to basically be automatic aggregators, which isn't what we're looking for)

I suppose I could investigate adding a feature to Press This, but that seems well beyond the scope of this project and what he'd want to pay for...

Comment: I think it'll be easier for you and cheaper for your client for you to teach him how to copy and paste and insert the featured image manually and you could create a custom field for the link to original post (and make it a required field)

Comment: Yeah, you may be right. I've proposed that to him as an option, so we'll see what he comes back with. Perhaps recording a video of myself doing some of these things may be a good way to help him out.